# Separate a record into multiple records for each column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a query in MS Access that is pulling in from 4 different tables, it shows an ID (that is common across the 4 tables) and 4 fields of totals, one is an Actual total, another a forecast total, etc

Thus, each record shows something like the following:

```
ID     | TotalActual | TotalForecast | TotalRR | TotalBudget

234518 | 90.10       | 150.98        |  152.31 |    149.0
```

Is there a way to divide this record so it shows up like the following:

```
Type     | ID     | Total  |

Actual   | 234518 | 90.10  | 

Forecast | 234518 | 150.98 |  

RR       | 234518 | 152.31 | 

Budget   | 234518 | 149.0  |
```

I don't want to make a union because the data needs to be able to refresh/update daily and I know that unions do not update when there are changes in the table/query

Comment: `I know that unions do not update when there are changes in the table/query` I'm afraid this is a false statement, please explain what you mean

Comment: If there is a change to a table/query, it will not automatically be in the union query
I would have to go and run the union query again for the update to be there. While with regular queries, changes to tables will automatically show up

Comment: If you refer to change in data, it is false, you will see actual data always. If you refer to changes in schema or table structure (changing a column name) it wont work even using UNION or not.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328828 this explains better than I can

Comment: @Horaciux is correct. Also, if you replace your current query with a UNION query that includes each of the four tables then you don't have to go through the trouble of joining them together (in your current query) only to hit that query four times and UNION the results to "unpivot" the data.

Comment: "When the query is a Union query, you cannot update data in the query."
So going the union route would still allow me to make edits to tables that would show up in the union query?

Comment: True, running a UNION query produces a recordset that is not updatable. So you cannot, for example, do `UPDATE MyUnionQuery SET FieldName=Value`. However, when changes are made to the underlying tables those changes *will* automatically appear the next time you run the UNION query.

Comment: So I just tried it and it's true! You can change the data

Can someone explain what they mean that you cannot update data in the query? I'm sorry, I'm still not understanding what functionality UNION queries do not have

Comment: `"When the query is a Union query, you cannot update data in the query."` That's correct. You don't want to update an union query, you want to update each table at a time.

Comment: basically you cannot do something like add expression fields to a union query like you can with a normal query?

Comment: If you mean calculated fields then yes, you can use those in a UNION query as well (within each individual SELECT query being UNIONed together). All they mean by "you cannot update data in the [UNION] query" is that, for example, if you open the UNION query in Datasheet view then you cannot type new values into the grid to update the underlying tables. However, you *can* update the underlying tables directly and then refresh the results of the UNION query (e.g., by hitting [F5]) to see the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

As revealed in the comments to the question, your aversion to using a UNION query was based on a misunderstanding of how those queries work and hence was unfounded. You do, in fact, want to use a UNION query *instead* of your current query (which presumably does an INNER JOIN on each of the four tables to produce five columns). The UNION query would be something like

```sql
    SELECT
        'Actual' AS [Type],
        [ID],
        [TotalActual] AS [Total]
    FROM [ActualTable]
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Forecast' AS [Type],
        [ID],
        [TotalForecast] AS [Total]
    FROM [ForecastTable]
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'RR' AS [Type],
        [ID],
        [TotalRR] AS [Total]
    FROM [RRTable]
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Budget' AS [Type],
        [ID],
        [TotalBudget] AS [Total]
    FROM [BudgetTable]
```